# When is the "null" publish ready?

Tags: meteor, publish

Having the following code on the server:

```js
Meteor.publish(null, function(){
    // Return some cursors.
})
```

will according to the documentation have the following effect: *the record set is automatically sent to all connected clients*.

How can I on the client side determine if all the documents published by this function has been received? If I would use a subscription instead, it would provide me with a ready callback, letting me know when all the documents been received. What's the matching way here? Or are the documents already received at the client when my client side code starts to execute?

Comment: BTW, if you require a decent control on when your data gets loaded, why don't you use a publish function with name?

Comment: @apendua Since this version exists, I thought it would be faster to use this variant than the traditional publish/subscribe variant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way to have a ready callback for so called `universal subscriptions` you mentioned above. Just have a look at [this part](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js#L966-L976) of Meteor's code, where the `publish` and `subscription` logic is defined on the server. For convenience I'm copy/pasting the code below:

```
ready: function () {
  var self = this;
  if (self._isDeactivated())
    return;
  if (!self._subscriptionId)
    return;  // unnecessary but ignored for universal sub
  if (!self._ready) {
    self._session.sendReady([self._subscriptionId]);
    self._ready = true;
  }
}
```

The `_subscriptionId` is only given to named subscriptions, which are those that you would manually define using `Meteor.subscribe` method. The subscriptions corresponding to `null` publish functions, doesn't have their own `_subscriptionId`, so as you can see from the code above, the server is not event trying to send the `ready` message to the client.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also confirm that the client hasn't received the documents before my app is loaded (in which case the ready callback is unnecessary)?

Comment: You may consider asking this as a separate question.  I put together a [test project](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-null-publish-test) which confirms that the client's Meteor.startup runs before null-published data gets there so I can see how this could be a problem.  See the project for a suggested workaround that may work for you (emulate 'ready' with a session var).

Comment: I agree with Adrian. I also made some experiments and it looks like the data is not loaded when the application is initialized. Which makes sense BTW, since otherwise the loading time could be affected.

Comment: @alanning I disagree with you (and apendua). My question is *When is the “null” publish ready?*, and if it would turn out that the documents are sent to the client along with my entire website when the clients connect, the null publish would be ready directly, and my question would be answered. But this doesn't seems to be the case. Thanks for your help!