# Categories not found, Meteor subscription

Tags: node.js, meteor

So, I'm looking to have the contents of the Categories collection of my Meteor application available at all times to the entire app.   I had read somewhere that you can do this by specifying `null` as the first parameter (instead of a name) to the `Meteor.publish` function.

I used the following code:

```
// Categories
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    return Categories.find();
});
```

When I launch my app, I get the following error as the application is starting up (the above segment of code is in `<app>/server/publications/global.js`):

```
Exception from sub id undefined ReferenceError: Categories is not defined
  at [object Object].Meteor.publish.Meteor.users.find.fields.username [as _handler] (app/server/publications/global.js:8:12)
  at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:950:1)
  at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:769:1)
  at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1437:1
```

The weird thing is, it says that but the publication seems to work fine.  Mongol is reporting that the Categories data is available throughout my app, and there are no other places that publish that data, so it must be coming from this call.

Any thoughts?  I'm sorta confused.   Should I check to see if Categories exists inside the sub before it returns, maybe?

Comment: where do you define Categories?

Comment: it probably re-ran and found categories on rerun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Matt K said (because comments suck and there's really bad code formatting in comments), a possible example of code that creates a named collection and maintains synchronization of its data between the connected clients and the server:

**/lib/collections.js** - runs on both server and client

```
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');
```

**/server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('categories', function() {
    return Categories.find();
});
```

**/lib/router.js** - (for Iron Router and tells all paths to wait until `my_collection` has been subscribed to before loading)

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('categories')
    ];
  }
});
```

Now what **you** did in the OP is create an un-named collection on the server and then publish it to all connected clients:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish

**/lib/collections.js**

```
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');
```

**/server/publications**

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    return Categories.find();
});
```

What this does is simply send all this data that it got from `Categories.find();` to the client in the form of a collection which has no name. Since it has no name, there is no direct way to easily tell when the client has successfully subscribed to it since it doesn't have anything for `waitOn` to look for, but there is a possible solution..

[When is the "null" publish ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890817/when-is-the-null-publish-ready)

https://github.com/alanning/meteor-null-publish-test

But in summary, publishing a null (un-named) collection to the client is goofy as hell since you don't know when the data will be available on each client. Avoid it if you can and just use the standard pub/sub pattern I described in the upper part of this post.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good solution.  I was unaware that I could use `waitOn` in `Router.configure`, and will do such.   Thank you very much.  If I could accept both your answers, I would.  I'm going to accept this one, because it sort of builds on the other, and contains what I suppose will be my final solution.

Comment: You can do `waitOn` in `Router.configure` (it takes an array of subscriptions)` and that causes ALL routes to subscribe to those publications. You can do `waitOn` on an individual route, and you can also do `waitOn` in a `RouteController`, which can also over-ride the global subscriptions in `Router.configure`

Comment: That's so awesome.  I love Meteor, the community is so helpful and great.  Thanks again for your fantastic answer, it was very useful and thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get a result, Meteor is doing 3 things...

1. Define the variable `Categories` (big fail)
2. Return the cursor on `Categories` before it has the data (this is what IR's `waitOn` is useful for)
3. Return the cursor on `Categories` with data (what you see after the blink of an eye)

Your app's problem is that it's trying to publish something before it even knows what it is. Then, once it finds out what it is, it reruns the publish, and everything is all good. That's an app loading order problem. Make sure your collection is defined on the client & server (usually in a folder named collections). Then, make sure your publish function is in a folder named server. In doing so, you're guaranteed your collections script is run before your publish script.

After this problem is solved, your next problem is going to be to code defensively. Just because you're always subscribed to `Categories` doesn't mean it'll always be available, it'll take time to subscribe.

For example, this:

```
doc = Categories.findOne();
if (!doc) return;
...
return doc && doc.createdAt;
```

Not this:

```
Categories.findOne().createdAt
```

This same logic could be applied to the publish function to solve your problem right now:

```
return Categories && Categories.find();
```

But I don't recommend it because that's an extra couple CPU cycles that you can avoid by ordering your docs correctly.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I guess I sort of figured it was a load order thing, it was the only way that it could throw an error and work at the same time.  Thank you very much.