# Meteor subscription in iron:router controller isn't working

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am using iron:router in my app and I have a controller that subscribes to one document in a collection by using a parameter in the path. I can access all of the documents in my collection on the server, so I know that there is stuff in there, but when I try to access the data that I subscribe to in the waitOn method of the controller, the data is undefined. Here is the relevant code for this problem.

Router code:

```js
this.route('unit', { path: 'unit/:unitId', template: 'unit', controller: 'UnitController' });

UnitController = BaseController.extend({
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('getUnit', this.params.unitId);
  },
  data: function () {
    var id = this.params.unitId;
    
    templateData = {
      unit: Collections.units.model(Collections.units.getUnit(id))
    };
    return templateData;
  }
});
```

Publication:

```js
Meteor.publish('getUnit', function(id) {
  return Collections.units.data.find({ unitId: id });
});
```

Here I have created an object for various things to do with my collection(I only included the important parts here):

```js
Collections.units = {
 data: new Mongo.Collection("units"),
 getUnit: function (id) {
  return this.data.findOne({ unitId: id });
 },
 model: function(unitEntity) {
       return {
         unitId: unitEntity.unitId,
         createdAt: unitId.createdAt,
         packets: unitEntity.packets,
         getLastPacket: function (id) {
         return _.last(this.packets);
         }
       };
    }
};
```

I have been trying to debug this for quite a while and I can do all the things to the collection I want to on the server and in the publish method, but when it gets to the controller, I can't access any of the info. In the data method this.params.unitId returns exactly what I want so that isn't the issue. Where the exception gets thrown is when I try to read properties of unitEntity when I'm making the model but that is just because it is undefined.

Have any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: my money is on the this in `getUnit`. Are you sure it will always be `Collections.units`? Similarly the this in `getLastPacket` seems a little dangerous. Browsers and node.js may not apply the same rules for defining `this`.

Comment: I know there are some bugs in other parts of the code. Ignore those. I am just worried about the subscription right now

Comment: please also be specific about the exception you are getting and where it is thrown.

Comment: @ChristianFritz If I log `Collections.data.findOne({ unitId: "123456" })` to the console I still get undefined ("123456" is the id of one of the units I have in there)

Comment: and you are on `unit/123456`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz The exception just says that it cannot read property 'unitId' of undefined when I am call `Collections.units.model(unit);` because the unit is undefined

Comment: your BaseController.extend looks a bit funny. Why not just add the waiton to the route definition itself? It seems that if you have any other routes, they may overwrite your waitOn

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes the route is unit/123456

Comment: You're defining your collections pretty weird. Check out my examples here for the "standard" way of doing collections.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944333/categories-not-found-meteor-subscription/30945391#30945391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that I was trying to solve's solution was to wrap the code inside the data method inside of `if (this.ready()){ ... }` and add an action hook with `if (this.data()) { this.render(); }`. After I got the subscription to work, I found that Christian was right in the comments with saying that my controller setup might mess things up. It was causing other strange exceptions which I fixed by just moving the hooks to each route instead of using the controller. As for my `Collections` setup, it may be unconventional, but all of that is working fine (as of right now). I may want to set them up the standard way at a later point, but as of right now its pretty handy for me to do things with the collections with the methods already written in the object.